# why do we need to specify paint while drawing bitmaps in custom view (android studio)

Tags: java, canvas

I wanted to make some pictures on a canvas in android studio, but i got stuck when it asked me for paint. I decoded the PNG files to bitmaps and wanted to use them but cant think what paint i should make and put.

I tried adding null as a paint but got more confused.
I don't think any code is required but here it is

```
canvas.drawBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getContext().getResources(), R.drawable.bird), i, 25 , redstroke);
```